# How to get the filename of a running PPS using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop, com-interop

I'm trying to make a .net 4.0 program which will get the filename of a PowerPoint Show (PPS) that is being viewed on the same machine.  The purpose is to time how long a particular presentation takes to go through without any user action.

I've tried the following:

```
 oPPTApp = (PowerPoint.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
 GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application");
 string ppsname = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Name.ToLower();
```

The program runs minimized while the presentation is being viewed.  Even while interacting with the PPS (scrolling through slides, clicking, etc), I get the following error from Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Application:

```
Application (unknown member) : Invalid request.  There is no active presentation.
```

After searching through http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285472, I tried adding:

```
oPPTApp.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

However, this started a new instance of PowerPoint, followed by the same error.

I'll also mention I'm using Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library and the IOleMessageFilter error handler from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228772(v=vs.110).aspx

Does ActivePresentation.Name not apply to PPS files?  Is there a better way of getting the filename of an open PPS?

Comment: Use Task Manager, Processes tab.  Check how many instances of powerpnt.exe are running.  More than one is too many.

Comment: I'm 100% certain only 1 instance is running while I try this without the oPPTApp.Visible line.  Adding this line starts another instance of powerpnt.exe, but the "no active presentation" error occurs either way.

Comment: Why are you not following my recommendation?  Tinkering with the Automation interface can leave extra copies of the process running that you cannot see but will be found by GetActiveObject().

Comment: It wasn't personal... and I absolutely did follow your advice, verified one instance of Powerpnt.exe *32 was running, and still got the error.  Do you know of a better way of doing this?  COM seems kind of unreliable now that you mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use plain old `System.Diagnostics.Process`?

The following code will give you the name of the active window of all processes with a given friendly name (process name without extension; in your case `"POWERPNT"`).

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public static IEnumerable<string> GetActiveMainWindowsTitle(string processName)
{
    var ps = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

    foreach (var p in ps)
        yield return p.MainWindowTitle;
}
```

The `MainWindowTitle` of a *MS PowerPoint* process is the name of the active presentation so if you are only looking for that info, this should do (you might need to clean the title a little if you are running, for example, a *Home and Student* version; usually there is a "non comercial use" tag on the main window title)